# Accessing a style file from a subfolder.

Tags: packages, subfiles

I am currently working on a project with a number of other students. Now we are performing a number of tests on a hydraulic rig. As we are progressing with our tests we write test reports with our findings, each test is given a folder with the data and the .jpg pictures from our preliminary evaluation of the data.

Now here is where things get complicated, we are using a template and style file to stream line the process, but since we are using a SVN repository i don't want to add our style file to each and every test folder. I can of course write the test report outside the folder and add the graphics with `\graphicspath{.../}` but the number of files will be substantial and I want to avoid this.

Is there a way to call a style file from a subfolder? And yes, I am aware that the best solution would be to include our style file in the `~/texmf/tex/latex/mystyles/` folder. 
However since I don't know how many will have access to these test reports today, or afterwards I thought I should make it as simple as possible.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well, the best solution is indeed to put the tex-file in your local `texmf` tree. You can ship out the the package with your files and instructions where to place it. People with some LaTeX knowledge can handle it, the rest won't use LaTeX anyway. What did you do in the end? Can you provide a self answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We solved the problem by building the test files in the top folder where the style file was saved, we then used a simple script to move the useful files to their respective subfolder.

It was not a pretty solution, but our inexperience with latex limited the options we could take.

The proper course of action and the simplest would be to just add the tex-file to ones local 
`texmf`tree as `Johannes_B` pointed out.