# How to access a style file outside of the current directory?

Tags: directory

**Disclaimer:** An [identical question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141424/accessing-a-style-file-from-a-subfolder) was asked 10 years ago with no answer. I would like to ask again in case someone, a decade later, has found a solution.

I have a folder that looks like this:

```
Phys1500
|   chaos.sty
+---Assignment1
|       1500HW1.tex
|       ...       
\---Tutorials
        ...
```

In my `1500HW1` file in the `Assignment1` folder, I would like to access the `chaos.sty` file in the parent directory. I have tried this with

```latex
\usepackage{chaos.sty}
```

to no effect. LaTeX can't *see* the `chaos.sty` file.

How may I access it? I don't simply want to move the style file to the directory of interest, because in the future I'll have more assignments that`ll all make use of that file.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: styles should normally  be in a texmf tree. So I would put it e.g. in texmflocal/tex/latex/mystyles, or create a new local texmf and put it there.

Comment: also it should be `\usepackage{chaos}` with no `.sty`

Comment: @AlanMunn It's a bit overkill. I only need the LaTeX files for this course (this Phys1500) folder to have access to them. Not every single one.

Comment: But your distribution is set up to have a place for local additions, and this is it. I have a letterhead package that I use only for letters, but it still goes there. You just need to put the package in `<yourpath>/texmf/tex/latex/<yourpackage>` and then forget about it. (Where <yourpath> will depend on your particular OS).

Comment: You could add a second directory to your `TEXMFHOME`, (see e.g. [How to make LaTeX see local texmf tree](//tex.stackexchange.com/a/30517) for Mac/Linux) but personally I don't think that is ever worth the effort. If you want to keep the files in a different location but still have them seen, you can simply add symbolic links to the folder in your home `texmf` folder instead (again, assuming Mac/Linux).